# read image from the database in python

Tags: python, database, image-processing

I wrote a code in python and I got the image from my computer as an object and now I want to get this image from MySQL database. Any idea how can I do it?

Here is my code for getting the image before connecting to the database, I read the image from my folder as an object:

```
segimg = Image.open("result1.png") 
segimg = segimg.convert("RGB")
```

I want to do the same but now from my database and here is the table of the desired image.

> Table: project
>
> project_name: varchar(25) (primary key)
>
> Image: longblob NOT NULL

Any idea how can I do it, and thanks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with python but your question bothered me so i did some researches to understand how things work and i did it anyway :p 
 
I hope this is the response you're looking for. Here you are the example i just did.

Connect to database, download the file and finally open it

Imports:

```
    import mysql.connector
    from tkinter import *
    from PIL import ImageTk, Image
```

Connect to the database:

```
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
     host="localhost",
     user="root",
     passwd="",
     database="mydb"
    )
```

Select the image and get the result:

```
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("SELECT image FROM project")
    myresult = mycursor.fetchone()
    blob = myresult[0]
```

Create a file from the query result:

```
    with open("filename.png", 'wb') as file:
        file.write(blob)
```

And finally open it with Tkinter:

```
    root = Tk()
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("filename.png"))
    panel = Label(root, image = img)
    panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much it was very helpful and it worked correctly